# How to define named channel consumer module deployment properties?

Tags: deployment, properties, channel, spring-xd, named

Given the following stream definition: "http | json-to-tuple > queue:job:process-data". How can I address the "process-data" deployment properties (like count and consumer concurrency - I'm using rabbitmq)?

I've tried module.*.count=0, but the process-data module always gets deployed in a single container (I've got a cluster with 2 containers). Also, when trying with module.process-data.count=0 spring-xd says that the only available modules are http and json-to-tuple.

I'm using spring-xd 1.2.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process-data` is not a module, it's just a named output channel for `json-to-tuple`.

It's a mechanism to connect two streams together;

```
foo | bar | baz
```

is the same as

```
foo | bar > xyz

xyz > baz
```

It gives a name `xyz` to the second `|` in the single stream.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. It seems that the count is defined at job deployment. I've deployed the job through the xd admin ui and specified count=0, but the job was deployed in a single container. When I deployed with the same config using xd shell then the job got deployed in all containers... maybe a bug in ui?

Comment: Which "job" ? `but the process-data module always gets deployed in a single container` - as I said, process-data is __not__ a module.

Comment: Ok, here what worked for me using xd shell: job deploy --name process-data --properties "module.process-data-module.count=0". Couldn't get process-data-module to get deployed in all containers using xd admin ui

Comment: OK; yes; it looks like a bug in the UI; if I deploy a job with a 0 count, I only get 1; deploying with 2 deploys 2 instances. Please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD).